# Tinymce is not showing in django admin

Tags: python, django, tinymce, admin, wysiwyg

I´ve installed tinymce on my localhost, and everything worked fine.
Then i copied it to the pythonanywhere server and there is only the normal content field witouht tinymce.
Maybe someone know where the problem is?

I´ve copied everything from my localhost, there everything worked.
Now he is searching in /static/ for the js of tinymce, but when i look into /static/ there are no tinmce files.
Is there anything wrong with the install on my server?

Every requirement is also satisfied.
Maybe someone has a tip for me where my mistake is?

The Error log says:

```
2019-05-17 13:24:28,011: Not Found: /favicon.ico
2019-05-17 13:24:35,743: Not Found: /static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
2019-05-17 13:24:35,878: Not Found: /static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js
2019-05-17 13:24:35,882: Not Found: /static/django_tinymce/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
2019-05-17 13:24:36,026: Not Found: /static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js
```

My settings file:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '0x!b#(1*cd73w$&azzc6p+essg7v=g80ls#z&xcx*mpemx&@9$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['dobricicuros.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'tinymce',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')


###########################################################################
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }
```

My URLs file:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.urls import include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    re_path(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tinymce.models import HTMLField


STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = HTMLField('Content')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

I defined the Static_ROOT and run collectstatic.
Now it shows me this ERROR:

```
2019-05-17 15:32:55,537: Not Found: /static/tiny_mce/themes/modern/editor_template.js
2019-05-17 15:32:55,544: Not Found: /static/tiny_mce/plugins/textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr            anchor pagebreak/editor_plugin.js
```

and this is my settings.py config part for tinymce:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'advanced',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you run collectstatic to put those files from tinymce into the static folder? Have you setup the correct [static file mapping](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles) on your PythonAnywhere webapp settings?

Comment: Now i run collectstatic after i defined in settings.py ---->>>>  STATIC_ROOT = "/home/UrosDobricic/mysite/static"

Now the field for the content is gone in the django admin panel. What can it be?

Comment: I´ve uploaded the new Error